# How to send Data to my App over USB Connection in Windows

Tags: android, usb

I have an app developed and deployed on my HTC mobile phone. I am able to debug this in Eclipse with the USB driver SDK. The mobile phone appears now in the hardware manager ADB interface.

I would now be able to send data through this USB connection to the mobile phone which my app is able to handle. I know some tethering software which does this, therefore there must be a way to communicate with user data and with my app.